# maximum and minimum - sentinel controlled repetition

Tags: c, max, minimum, sentinel

I have to find the maximum and the minimum using a sentinel controlled repetition.

"maximum” is not working properly. Can anyone help me with some clue about what’s wrong in my code?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() { 
  int number;
  int min;
  int max;

  do {
    printf("Enter a number (-1 to quit): ");
    scanf("%d",&number);
    if( number >= 0 ) {
      if(number < min )
        min = number;
      if( number > max )
        max = number;

    }
    else if( number < 1 )
      printf("the number is not valid \n");
  } 

  while( number != -1 );

  printf("Minimum=%d\n",min);
  printf("Maximum=%d\n",max);

  system("pause");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should initialize local variables.

Comment: Enter a number (-1 to quit): 44
Enter a number (-1 to quit): 32
Enter a number (-1 to quit): 2
Enter a number (-1 to quit): -1
the number is not valid 
Minimum=2
Maximum=2674276
(Maximum is not working). :/

Comment: @Marc it's working. I set max = 0. Why dont I need to initialize "min"?

Comment: one sec, im writing my answer how to set min and max

Comment: @Nomics my answer is updated

Comment: In plus, I think your professor would like to see a 3*N/2 complexity, not 2*N complexity as you did. For this, you group the elements in pairs of 2, and write 3 comparaisons in each branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of your variables not initialized were 2674276, all numbers were smaller so your min was fine

but no number was bigger than this so it was your max.

You need to initialize your min and your max with the first number

I would do something like

```
max = -1
min = -1

do {
    printf("Enter a number (-1 to quit): ");
    scanf("%d",&number);
    if( number >= 0 ) {
      if(max == -1)
      {
         max = number //Means it's the first time so your max and min are the first number
         min = number
      }
      else
      {
         if(number < min )
            min = number;
         if( number > max )
          max = number;

      }
    }
    else if( number < 1 )
      printf("the number is not valid \n");
  } 

  while( number != -1 );
```

Comment: All of them which you use before assigning a value. That's min and max, but not number.

Comment: Better to initialise `int max = INT_MIN; int min = INT_MAX;`, so you're not hosed if the user enters only numbers `> min` or `< max`.

Comment: Good point, it's another way to do it